# Nesting while loop inside a while loop in cshell

Tags: while-loop, nested, tcsh

I need my code to read files that are numbered between 1 and 4000. It will then do something with the files, I am trying to break them up in blocks of 500 with the following.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

@ x = 1

@ looper = 1

while ($x < 3)
while ($looper < 500)

@filenumber = $x -1
@filenumber = $filenumber * 500
@filenumber = $filenumber + $looper

echo $filenumber
@looper += 1
done

@x += 1
done
```

I want this to count from 1 to 1000 in units of 500. However when I try this the script only counts to 500. Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `@looper = 1` *inside* the outer loop, otherwise it gets initialized only once, and starts the second iteration with the value 500.

```
@ x = 1

while ($x < 3)

@looper = 1   <-- here

while ($looper < 500)

@filenumber = $x -1
@filenumber = $filenumber * 500
@filenumber = $filenumber + $looper

echo $filenumber
@looper += 1
done

@x += 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that right beneath the @x +=1 line there needs to be a line resetting the $looper variable

```
@x += 1
@looper = 1
done
```

WHOOPS!!!